# Html php Javascript class not work dynamically. by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Question from beginner.

I just try made photo gallery website by sample site template.
My photos located in local folder to IIS server.

First job is to load all subfolders from mainfolders: This works fine!

```
<li class="colorlib-active">
   <?php
    if ($handle = opendir('images')) {
          while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && $entry != ".htaccess" && $entry != ".htpasswd"){                                 
             echo '<a href="#" onclick=photogallery("images/'.$entry.'")> '.$entry.'</a><br>';                                                                          }
           }
         closedir($handle);
       }                                              
    ?> 
</li>
```

Then function photogallery(): after cliking subfolder, then we can find all jpg-files and attribute them.
This works also fine!

```
    <script>   
    function photogallery($dir){
        $.ajax({
          url: $dir,
          success: function(data){ 
                $(data).find('a[href$=".jpg"]').each(function () { 
                var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("https://", "");
                var fileurl = filename;
                var para = document.createElement("div");
                para.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4 ftco-animate");                       
                var para2 = document.createElement("a");
                para2.setAttribute("href",  filename);                       
                para2.setAttribute("class", "photography-entry img image-popup d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center");                       
                para2.setAttribute("style", "background-image: url("+fileurl+");");                                              
                document.getElementById("photoplace").appendChild(para).appendChild(para2);                
            });
          }
        });
    }             
    </script>
```

This updates dynamically div photoplace:

```
<section class="ftco-section-2">
    <div class="photograhy">
        <div class="row no-gutters" id="photoplace">
         </div>                                                                                
        </div>
</section>
```

So problem is, pictures does not showing in page because class ftco-animate won't work.
I remove this class and now i see pictures. After cliking picture class image-popup won't work.

Still if i call directly function without ajax:

```
<script>   
function test($dir2){
      var para = document.createElement("div");
      para.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4 ftco-animate");                       
      var para2 = document.createElement("a");
      para2.setAttribute("href",  $dir2);                       
      para2.setAttribute("class", "photography-entry img image-popup d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center");                       
      para2.setAttribute("style", "background-image: url("+$dir2+");");                                              
      document.getElementById("photoplace").appendChild(para).appendChild(para2);       
    }       
</script>
```

By call:
`test("images/folder1/IMG_20200410_0128.jpg");`  This works fine!

Could you please tell what happend code inside ajax or where this is going wrong?
Thanks.

Chrome console show following errors:

```
js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:126 Uncaught pd {message: "Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed null.", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new pd (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…init (myurladdress/js/google-map.js:44:15)"}message: "Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed null."name: "InvalidValueError"stack: "Error↵    at new pd (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:56:227)↵    at Object._.qd (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:56:337)↵    at new Gi (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:126:50)↵    at init (myurladdress/js/google-map.js:44:15)"__proto__: Error
Gi @ js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:126
init @ google-map.js:44
load (async)
_.N.addDomListener @ js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:184
(anonymous) @ google-map.js:62
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for myurladdress/js/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for myurladdress/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for myurladdress/js/aos.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for myurladdress/css/aos.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
util.js:230 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required
uz.o @ util.js:230
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:140
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:140
setTimeout (async)
Aj @ js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:140
google.maps.Load @ js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:14
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:233
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false:233
```

and:

```
throw _.qd("Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed "+a+".");if("string"===typeof a)throw _.qd("Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed string '"+a+"'.");var d=b||{};d.noClear||_.Bi(a);var e="undefined"==typeof document?null:document.createElement("div");e&&a.appendChild&&(a.appendChild(e),e.style.width=e.style.height="100%");if(!(_.z.devicePixelRatio&&_.z.requestAnimationFrame||_.Tg[43]))throw _.P("controls").then(function(m){m.Oh(a)}),
```

Update! Please forget previous and after many hours of checking i have one question!

What difference is next two ways make function call? (because last one works propely!)

```
<script>
function loadimages(){
        $imurl ="photos/gallery1/IMG_20200410_0128.jpg";
                    var para = document.createElement("div");
                    var para.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4 ftco-animate");                       
                    para2 = document.createElement("a");
                    para2.setAttribute("href", $imurl);                       
                    para2.setAttribute("class", "photography-entry img image-popup d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center");                       
                    para2.setAttribute("style", "background-image: url('"+$imurl+"');");                                              
                    document.getElementById("photoplace").appendChild(para).appendChild(para2);       
}

document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function () { loadimages(); };          
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
function loadimages(){
        $imurl ="photos/gallery1/IMG_20200410_0128.jpg";
                    var para = document.createElement("div");
                    var para.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4 ftco-animate");                       
                    para2 = document.createElement("a");
                    para2.setAttribute("href", $imurl);                       
                    para2.setAttribute("class", "photography-entry img image-popup d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center");                       
                    para2.setAttribute("style", "background-image: url('"+$imurl+"');");                                              
                    document.getElementById("photoplace").appendChild(para).appendChild(para2);       
}

loadimages();         
</script>
```

Really, why this last code working propely and html button can't activate function propely?

Comment: You should debug it on your end: what does your ajax call return (look in browser console)? Are there any hyperlinks which would even respond to `$(data)`, let alone the `.find(...)`, or does all that just return an empty list?

Comment: Ok, i write response to previous message!